# Efficient recursive vector

Tags: r

I am trying to speed up a Monte Carlo function.  I want to tighten this up but I can't figure out how.  Any ideas?

```
initial=1400
ppinitial=0.07
assets2020=numeric(41)    
actual=round(seq(from=initial, to=0, by=(-initial/40)),0)*100000
assets2020[1]=1000000*1.02-actual[1]*ppinitial
for (i in 2:length(actual)){
  assets2020[i]=assets2020[i-1]*1.02-actual[i]*ppinitial}
```

Comment: Throws an error for missing value of 'ppinitial'

Answer (score 1):

I think that you can use `filter` here:

```
assets2020 <- -ppinitial * filter(actual,1.02,'rec',init=-1000000/ppinitial)
```

### demo:

```
y[i]=y[i-1]*1.02-x[i]*pp  ## use y ,x notation more handy than long variables
```

can be rewritten:

```
Y[i]= x[i]+f[1]*Y[i-1]  ## recursive filter expression
```

Where `Y = -y/pp` and `f[1]=1.02`

Or `Y[1]=x[1]+f[1]*1000000` so `init` is equal to `-1000000/ppinitial`

#### PS : example for some:

```
ppinitial =100
filter_asset <- -ppinitial * filter(actual,1.02,'rec',init=-1000000/ppinitial)
sum(abs(filter_asset-assets2020))

[1] 0.001937866
```

Comment: For a given `ppinitial`, this doesn't produce the same vector as the OP's approach.

Comment: @jbaums You are right. There is an error on the init value. fixed now. See my edit.

Comment: Thank you.  The filter_asset vector does not look like the vector my original code returns.  But thank you for this function -- I will try to understand what it does using the documentation.